# laravel only searching for id 1

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a `laravel` forum project. Now, what I did is I created categories and subcategories, I made subcategories display under categories and now I'm making threads. So for threads when you're creating them you choose a subcategory to which it belongs to for example development.

Now when I open a subcategory Development and let's say for example in database development subcategory is id 7, I created a relation in subcategories model and when i want to display all threads in that subcategory I loop with that has Many relation, this is the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Subcategory extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable=['name', 'category_id'];

        public function threads()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Thread', 'subcategory_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```

and now when I want to loop through the subcategories and get threads with that subcategory id i do this:

```
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('content')




    @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)

        @foreach($subcategory->threads as $topic)
            <p>{{$topic->name}}</p>
        @endforeach

    @endforeach

@endsection
```

Keep in mind that for example subcategory_ id is 7 and my query outputs

```
SQL: select * from `threads` where `threads`.`subcategory_id` = 1 and `threads`.`subcategory_id` is not null)
```

Routes:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

        Route::get('category/new', 'CategoryController@newCategory');
        Route::post('category/create', 'CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');

        Route::post('sub/store', 'SubcategoryController@store')->name('subcategory.store');

        Route::get('/category/{id}', 'SubcategoryController@display')->name('subcategory.display');
    });

Controller:

    public function display()
    {
        $threads = Thread::get();
        $subcategories = Subcategory::get();
        return view('thread.index', compact('threads', 'subcategories'));
    }
```

Can you please look at the code and try to explain to me what is causing the problem ?

Comment: There isn't a single question mark in your question. Can you try to write a question?

Comment: There it is, but I don't understand your complaint, I explained everything pretty clear here.

Comment: Is the query wrong? Or are the results wrong? What do you expect to happen from the query? What actually happens?

Comment: Yes the query is wrong. As I explained it's always looking for subcategory_id to be one even if im looking for subcategory_id 7

Comment: What is the code in the controller?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Maybe try adding a {{$subcategory->id}} inside the subcategory for loop so you can verify what the id of the subcategory is for every group of threads. At this point it looks like an issue with your data and not so much with the code.

Comment: well if i do @foreach($subcategory->id->threads as $topic) i get Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you want show every thread for every sub category ? if yes what is {id} in  /category/{id}?

Comment: no i want to show only threads for the subcategory they belong to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller :

```
  public function display($id)
   {
    $threads = Thread::where('subcategory_id',$id)->get();
    return view('thread.index', compact('threads'));
   }
```

view:

```
        @foreach($threads as $topic)
            <p>{{$topic->name}}</p>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: you want for one subcategories?

Comment: No let me explain it clearer.
I have subcategories, and threads, every thread has a subcategory and in table there is subcategory_id so i want to display threads with that subcategory_id that is in link for example localhost:8000/category/5 and if in thread there are rows with subcategory_id 5 then display them in the loop